# Metaplex JS SDK returning null when jsonLoaded is True

Tags: metaplex, metaplex-js, nfts

I'm having an issue while trying to get an NFT's JSON data. Regardless of mint address, I keep getting `null`.

(Using `@metaplex-foundation/js@0.17.12` on a free QuickNode RPC).

I'm trying the following:

```
const mintAddress = new PublicKey("AHWC8Jb4vXNKJi7ypVN3fKcsXrWXqJDc7Jdfa2FSxvp7");
const x = await metaplex.nfts().findByMint({ mintAddress });
```

The mint address above is just a random Claynosaurz.
The data that's returned is showing `model: "nft"` and `jsonLoaded: true`, but the `json` field comes back as `null`.

I came across a post in the SDK's repo "issues" page, that `null` is returned when invalid json is returned. However, this seems to be the case for any mint address I try. I suspect it's probably an issue on my end.

Has anyone come across a similar issue or have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I have same problem. Let me know if you find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow
Products
Getting this error with the @metaplex-foundation/js-next SDK
Asked 1 year, 6 months ago
Modified 4 months ago
Viewed 1k times
1

Currently working on a react app and I'm getting this error after installing metaplex. My react-scripts version is 4.0.3

./node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/js-next/dist/esm/programs/token/gpaBuilders/TokenGpaBuilder.mjs
Can't import the named export 'ACCOUNT_SIZE' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
metaplex
Share
Improve this question
Follow
edited Jul 24, 2022 at 1:37
Sercan's user avatar
Sercan
4,90733 gold badges1919 silver badges3737 bronze badges
asked Jul 24, 2022 at 1:27
Nebson's user avatar
Nebson
3644 bronze badges
Add a comment

Report this ad
2 Answers
Sorted by:

Highest score (default)
2

I found out the solution in the git of metaplex here. I will leave you here the whole answer anyway.

Getting Started with Metaplex and CRA 5 This example sets up a new React app with Metaplex using "Create React App" (CRA) version 5 — i.e. using Webpack 5.

This example has been generated using the following steps:

Create a new project using the "Create React App" command.

npx create-react-app getting-started-react-cra5
cd getting-started-react-cra5
Install the Metaplex and the Solana SDKs.

npm install @metaplex-foundation/js @solana/web3.js
Install some polyfills.

npm install assert util crypto-browserify stream-browserify
Install and use react-app-rewired.

## Installs react-app-rewired.

npm install react-app-rewired

## Replaces "react-scripts" with "react-app-rewired" in package.json scripts.

sed -i '' 's/react-scripts /react-app-rewired /g' package.json
Override Webpack 5 configurations.

Create a new file to override Webpack 5 configurations.

touch config-overrides.js
Copy the following code inside the new config-overrides.js file.

const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = function override(webpackConfig) {
// Disable resolving ESM paths as fully specified.
// See: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11467#issuecomment-691873586
webpackConfig.module.rules.push({
test: /.m?js/,
resolve: {
fullySpecified: false,
},
});

// Ignore source map warnings from node_modules.
// See: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/11752
webpackConfig.ignoreWarnings = [/Failed to parse source map/];

// Polyfill Buffer.
webpackConfig.plugins.push(
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"] })
);

// Polyfill other modules.
webpackConfig.resolve.fallback = {
crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
util: require.resolve("util"),
assert: require.resolve("assert"),
fs: false,
process: false,
path: false,
zlib: false,
};

return webpackConfig;
};
Update your browser requirements.

Update the browserslist object of your package.json to include the following production requirements.

"browserslist": {
"production": [

- ```
  ">0.2%",
  ```
- ```
  "not dead",
  ```
- ```
  "not op_mini all"
  ```

- ```
  "chrome >= 67",
  ```
- ```
  "edge >= 79",
  ```
- ```
  "firefox >= 68",
  ```
- ```
  "opera >= 54",
  ```
- ```
  "safari >= 14"
  ```

  ],
  "development": [
  "last 1 chrome version",
  "last 1 firefox version",
  "last 1 safari version"
  ]
  },
  That's it!

Comment: Looks like a copy paste from somewhere. Please post meaningful answers. This is a copy paste and not even answer to the original question.